# How to convert array multidimensional array to single array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

my output is

```
Array ( [bid] => 1 [bookiing_date] => 2014-11-19 ) 
Array ( [bid] => 2 [bookiing_date] => 2014-11-15 ) 
Array ( [bid] => 3 [bookiing_date] => 2015-01-10 ) 
Array ( [bid] => 4 [bookiing_date] => 2015-01-27 )
```

but i want to convert in this form..

```
$date = ['2015-01-10','2015-01-27','2014-11-19'];
```

Please any one help me

Comment: Array ( [bid] => 1 [bookiing_date] => 2014-11-19 ) 
Array ( [bid] => 2 [bookiing_date] => 2014-11-15 ) 
Array ( [bid] => 3 [bookiing_date] => 2015-01-10 ) 
Array ( [bid] => 4 [bookiing_date] => 2015-01-27 )

this is my ouput from controller 
i am trying to store this output in single variable like this

$date = ['2015-01-10','2015-01-27','2014-11-19'];

Comment: You have only written your array.. What code did you try to convert the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written above doesn't look too much like PHP, but something like this should do the trick

```
$single_dimensional_array = array();
foreach($multi_dimensional_array as $array_item) {
    if(isset($array_item['bookiing_date'])) {
         $single_dimensional_array[] = $array_item['bookiing_date'];
    }
}

echo(var_export($single_dimensional_array), true);
```

Btw, the `$single_dimensional_array[] =` syntax above simply pushes the value on the right side of the equal sign onto the end of the array on the left side of the equal sign.

Comment: but your output not match my output what i want.
this is your o/p
array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "'2014-11-19'" [1]=> string(12) "'2014-11-15'" [2]=> string(12) "'2015-01-10'" [3]=> string(12) "'2015-01-27'" }

i want this output..

$date = ['2015-01-10','2015-01-27','2014-11-19'];

Comment: Ah, my output above was just meant to be a sample.  With another `foreach` statement over the `$single_dimensional_array`, you can easily produce that exact output using some `echo` statements

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple approach to get that... I think you did not tried anyway..here is the basic and simple answer ...

```
$sing_arr = array();
$multi_arr = array(array ( "bid"=> 1, "bookiing_date"=> "2014-11-19" ) ,
array ( "bid"=> 2, "bookiing_date"=> "2014-11-15" ) ,
array ( "bid"=> 3, "bookiing_date"=> "2015-01-10" ) ,
array ( "bid"=> 4 ,"bookiing_date"=> "2015-01-27" )
);

foreach($multi_arr as $key=>$val)
{
    array_push($sing_arr,"'".$val["bookiing_date"]."'");
}
echo var_dump($sing_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Loop Through the array using `foreach` and store the date in another array:

**Code:**

```
<?php 
$array1=array(
        Array ( "bid" => 1 ,"bookiing_date" => "2014-11-19" ),
        Array ( "bid" => 2 ,"bookiing_date" => "2014-11-15" ),
        Array ( "bid" => 3 ,"bookiing_date" => "2015-01-10" ),
        Array ( "bid" => 4 ,"bookiing_date" => "2015-01-27" )
);
// print_r($array1);
$date=array();
foreach ($array1 as $temparray){
    $date[]=$temparray["bookiing_date"];
}
print_r($date);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2014-11-19
    [1] => 2014-11-15
    [2] => 2015-01-10
    [3] => 2015-01-27
)
```

Comment: hey 

i use your code but output is 

array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "'2014-11-19'" [1]=> string(12) "'2014-11-15'" [2]=> string(12) "'2015-01-10'" [3]=> string(12) "'2015-01-27'" }



i want only

 $var=['2014-10-10','2014-10-12'];

like this..

Comment: The array will be indexed starting from zero.
Seems you are using var_dump() to print the output

Comment: Even if you manually run this code `$var=['2014-10-10','2014-10-12'];
var_dump($var);` you will get output as `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2014-10-10"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2014-10-12"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$array = array(array('bid' => 1, 'bookiing_date' => 2014 - 11 - 19),
    array('bid' => 2, 'bookiing_date' => 2014 - 11 - 15),
    array('bid' => 3, 'bookiing_date' => 2015 - 01 - 10),
    array('bid' => 4, 'bookiing_date' => 2015 - 01 - 27));
$data = array();
foreach ($array as $array_item){
    if(isset($array_item['bookiing_date'])) {
         $data[] = $array_item['bookiing_date'];
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

if you are using PHP 5.5+, use array_column()

```
$data = array_column($array, 'bookiing_date');
print_r($data);
```